# Creat multi select on the fly please

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying this for a while already, I need to create multi select inputs on the fly, here's my approach:

http://pizzariadomcattione.com.br/addbut/

Please, how do I go about that ?

Tks in advance !!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title>Pizzaria - Dei Trulli</title>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="magicsuggest.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="magicsuggest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


                        <p class="lead"><div id="ms1" class="form-control" value='["Chicago","Houston"]'></div></p>


<a id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info" href="#"> + Mais uma pizza </a>

<div id="InputsWrapper">

    <div>
        <input id="field_1" type="text" value="Text 1" name="mytext[]"></input>
        <a class="removeclass" href="#"> × </a>
    </div>
</div>










<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
    {
            if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
            {
                FieldCount++; //text box added increment
                //add input box
                //$(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'" value="Text '+ FieldCount +'"/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
                $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><p class="lead2"><div id="ms2" class="form-control" value=""></div></p><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');


                x++; //text box increment
            }
    return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            if( x > 1 ) {
                    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                    x--; //decrement textbox
            }
    return false;
    })

    });





$(function() {
    $('.lead').each(function () {
        var ms = $(this).magicSuggest({data : [ 'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston',
                                                'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix', 'San Antonio',
                                                'San Diego', 'Dallas', 'San Jose', 'Jacksonville' ],
        name: 'sabores'
        });
    });
});


$(function() {
    $('#ms2').eac   h(function () {
        var ms = $(this).magicSuggest({data : [ 'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston',
                                                'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix', 'San Antonio',
                                                'San Diego', 'Dallas', 'San Jose', 'Jacksonville' ],
       name: 'bebidas'
            });
    });
});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And wont add the new button with the multi select inside, help please, I'm kind of new in here, tks

Comment: Post some code not just a link

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Please post a minimal specific example of the code you're having a problem with and a description of the problem

Comment: I've posted the link with all i've tryed, open the link you will see where I stopped please, it wont add the select correctly, not sure why: 

http://pizzariadomcattione.com.br/addbut/

Tks

Comment: Please take a look at the [help]. You should post your code _in your question_. Given that you've now linked to it twice I'm tempted to treat this as spam.

Comment: Mike, sorry for the second link, but what's wrong with oppening the link and looking at the code ? How will I post all the code in here ? It's all in the link, no errors

Comment: Impossible to paste code in here: too long by 2608 characters

Comment: Ok, I've a a multi select input, and I want to add other multi selects everytime I click in the ADD Button, so when I click in add button, it will add the multi select, it's almost working, but there's something I'm missing, you can see the entire code in the link I've sent you, tks

Comment: Please, could someone give me a hand with this please ??

Comment: ok, a jsfiddle example, I'm almost there, anyhelp is welcome, please:

http://jsfiddle.net/PM5Fq/1/

Comment: more improvements,  http://jsfiddle.net/PM5Fq/8

Answer (score 0):

Solved it out, thanks a lot

http://jsfiddle.net/PM5Fq/19/

Here's the magic:

```
 var addButtonS     = $("#addMoreFileBoxSabor")
 $(addButtonS).click (function (e) {
  if (inputsWrapper.children().length <= maxInputs) {
    var new_dropdown = document.createElement ('p')
    new_dropdown.className = 'lead'
    new_dropdown.innerHTML = '<div class="form-control" value=""></div>'
    //data_set.name = "sabores" + inputsWrapper.get(0).childNodes.length
    inputsWrapper.append (new_dropdown)
    console.log (data_set_sabor.name)
    $(new_dropdown).magicSuggest(data_set_sabor)
   }
  return false
 })
```